# Am I correct or is the solution correct? I am pretty sure I am the one that is correct.

Tags: permutations, combinations

John and Mary are members of a group of eight boys and two girls. In how many ways can a committee of five be chosen from the the same group of ten if either John or Mary is in it but not both?

**My working:** We consider it into two separate cases, only when John is in the committee and only when Mary is in the committee. Only when John in the committee, we can choose the remaining 4 from 8 people excluding John and Mary, so we have $^8C_{4}$. Similarly for the case when only Mary is in the committee, so in total we have $2\times ^8C_{4}$.

But the explanation in the solution says $^{10}C_{5}-^8C_{3}$ which I think is not correct, because they subtract by $^8C_{3}$ which is the case of both of them is in the committee, but we also need to subtract by $^8C_{5}$, the case where none of them is in the committee.

And there is another version of the solution which says $^{9}C_{5}\times 2-^8C_{3}$. I don't quite understand how did they get this, but numerically it is the same as $^{10}C_{5}-^8C_{3}$. Can anyone please explain?

Just want to make sure, am I wrong or is the solution wrong? I am pretty sure I am correct. Helps with explanation are really appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: You are right.${}{}$

Comment: I second André, you're right.

Comment: If you want to use their method, the answer is $\binom{10}{5}-\binom{8}{3}-\binom{8}{5}$, which happens to be $\binom{10}{5}-2\binom{8}{3}$.

Comment: Yep you are right.

Comment: Thanks all! I know I must be right :)

Answer (score 0):

It wants you to use complementary counting: count all possibilities and subtract the impossible ones. All possibilities are represented by 10 choose 5.

Anyway what I do know is that the 9 choose 5 times two represents just one person; John or Mary being chosen. You subtract 8 choose 3 because that is the number of ways they can both be picked. That one makes sense. You can think of it like 8 subtracting 8 choose (5 - both John and mary) which is equal to 8 choose 3.

**EDIT: Made a minor mistake. You are right; book is 100% wrong. Let's say you pick John and put Mary aside, leaving 4 slots and 8 people. 8 choose 4. Let's say you pick Mary and put John aside, leaving 4 slots and 8 people. 8 choose 4. Therefore the answer is, without a shadow of a doubt 2(8C4).**

Comment: Thanks. But in the case of complementary counting, shouldn't we also consider both of them in the committee as impossible as well?